# Erasing a part of circle stroke in illustrator with rounded edges

Tags: adobe-illustrator, stroke

I need to create a circle stroke that doesn't form a complete circle. The ends of the stroke should be rounded.

I am using Illustrator. I also have attached the sample. Would someone please be able to show me how I can do this?

[image: Finger pointing into concentric circles, which have a section cut out underneath the finger]

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?For example how are you using round edges, with the photoshop effect? Adding a picture will get you a long way!

Comment: i need to create this with illustrator..

Comment: Hi balaji, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. Could you tell us what you tried that didn't work? Always good to show some effort, and your chances for a good answer increase. If you have any questions, please see the [help center](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help) or ping one of us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot) once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 3):

Ok so there's no need for "rounded roners":

1. Draw a Circle
2. Cut it wherecer you want by adding 2 point on the stroke and then selecting one with the direct selection tool and pressing backspace or delete:
   [image]

[image]

3. Go to the Strokes window and choose the rounded cap:

[image]

*If needed make an outline stroke: `object> outline stroke` (the right one is with outline stroke):

[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer, but could you please say me how to cut the circle stroke without converting it to outline stroke..

Comment: edited my answer

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do it, but this is the simplest one.

[image]